# Spring repository interface: query methods by type

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I wonder if it is possible to specify a specific subtype with springs' [query methods](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.8.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation).

For example, if there is a `MailUser` and `ChatUser`, both `extend User` with `InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE` - can I find all `MailUser`s with the `PersonRepository`?

Or can I find all `User`s excluding all `MailUser`s in a scenario where multiple classes `extend User`?

```
public interface PersonRepository extends Repository<User, Long> {

  List<Person> findByEmailAddressAndLastname(EmailAddress emailAddress, String lastname);
...
}
```

Comment: What does your database table(s) look like?  What kind of inheritance mapping are you using?

Comment: oops, forgot to mention `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)`

Comment: Can you select by discriminator?

Comment: AFAIK, no. But you can simply create a ChatUserRepository and a MailUserRepository.

Comment: in this minimalistic example probably. In my use case I have 22 subtypes and need to find 21 subtypes excluding just one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do it with the automatic query creation based on the method names, Spring Data does not support it (see [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation) for the supported expressions). However, you can [use `@Query`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query) to specify a JPQL query by hand and use the `TYPE(entity)` operator in the `WHERE` clause to narrow down to a particular entity type. See [JPA spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html) *4.6.17.5 Entity Type Expressions*:

> An entity type expression can be used to restrict query polymorphism. The `TYPE` operator returns the exact type of the argument.
>
> *[...]*
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> SELECT e
> FROM Employee e
> WHERE TYPE(e) IN (Exempt, Contractor)
>
> SELECT e
> FROM Employee e
> WHERE TYPE(e) IN (:empType1, :empType2)
>
> SELECT e
> FROM Employee e
> WHERE TYPE(e) IN :empTypes
>
> SELECT TYPE(e)
> FROM Employee e
> WHERE TYPE(e) <> Exempt
> ```